# Problem related to center of circle bisecting circumferences of other circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Coordinates of the center of the circle which bisects the circumference of the circles

$x^2+y^2=1\quad$
$x^2+y^2+2x-3=0\quad$
$x^2+y^2+2y-3=0 \quad$

is.....

$A(-1,-1)\quad
B(3,3)\quad
C(2,2)\quad
D(-2,-2)\quad$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please consider using MathJax to format your questions. A basic guide can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the given circles are
$$x^2+y^2=1,\quad  (x+1)^2+y^2=2^2\, \quad x^2+(y+1)^2=2^2.$$
Moreover a circle $C_1$ bisects a circle $C_2$ iff the common chord (i.e. the segment that joins the intersection points) passes through the center of circle $C_2$.
So if the circle of center $(t,t)$ bisects the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ it follows that its radius $r$ is 
$$(x-t)^2+(y-t)^2=r^2\implies \underbrace{(x^2+y^2)}_{=1}-2t\cdot \underbrace{(x+y)}_{=0}+2t^2=r^2\implies r=\sqrt{2t^2+1}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I did not understand the part where you evaluated r

Comment: I am intersecting the circle  $(x-t)^2+(y-t)^2=r^2$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and I want that the common chord is the line $y=-x$ (the line through the center $(0,0)$ which is orthogonal to the line $y=x$ joining the centers).

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Thanks a lot!